# Why do I keep getting codeigniter "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error with AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following problem happening consistently on my code.

I have a data model with the following function:
**data_model.php**

```
public function testFunc(){
        return "string";
}
```

**site.php** (controller)

```
public function get_more_data(){
    $this->load->model('data_model');
    $data['test']=$this->data_model->testFunc();
    return $data;
}
```

**home.php** (view)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button class="test">test</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        $('.test').click(function(){
        $id=1;
        $.ajax
        ({  
            url: '<?php echo site_url() ?>index/site/get_more_data',
            data: $id,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result)
            {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
</html>
```

However every time I click the button I always get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[::1]/codeignitor/index.phpindex/site/get_more_data. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What am I doing wrong or not understanding correctly here?

Thanks,

Comment: your function `site_url()` is returning `http://[::1]/codeignitor/index.php`. i'd check that first

Comment: looks like ipv6

Answer (score 0):

I use ajax in my CodeIgniter projects using the following procedure :
I send data to controllers using queries (like : xxxx.com?id=5)
I receive data using echo in the controller